# How does one report the results of a linear model?

Tags: regression, linear-model, reporting, social-science

What are the established best practices for reporting the results of a linear model in journals in the social sciences?

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure if there are established best practices across social science as a whole - different fields have different professional associations that may have different approaches. Regardless, the reporting wholly depends on things like what the model is answering, the journal, etc. But I guess here are some things I personally like to see:

1. Actual interpretation of coefficients in the units of the variables included (rather that “and this coefficient is X”)
2. A discussion about the relative magnitude of coefficients compared to what we think is a “practically” significant change in y
3. Acknowledgement of model fit statistics and what they mean for interpretation of results